# Clarification on recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

[Recurrence relation for number of ternary strings that contain two consecutive zeros](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127818/recurrence-relation-for-number-of-ternary-strings-that-contain-two-consecutive-z/2721193#2721193)

On the link above, how can I use the formula for two consecutive 2s? I'm new to this and I'm not sure if it's valid for either 0s, 1s or 2s or just consecutive 0s.

Second question, regarding this link: [Prove sequence with fibonacci recurrence bounded by $(7/4)^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/939841/prove-sequence-with-fibonacci-recurrence-bounded-by-7-4n/2721164#2721164)

is it also possible for n>= 2?

Thank you!

Comment: The answer is the same for 0's, 1's or 2's.  Just substitute "2" for "0" everywhere in the proof.

Comment: There are no "0"s in the proof though

Comment: I see several zeros in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127822/468350).

Comment: I was talking about the final answer for the recurrence relation, sorry.

Comment: @KenmourNoble Yes, you get the same answer if you transform the proof as described.